# pkcs11 support got Gnome NetworkManager OpenVPN

Tags: linux, gnome, networkmanager, vpn, openvpn

I noticed in the release notes of Gnome NetworkManager OpenVPN plugin I noticed since version 1.8.0 that does seem to be some support for using pkcs 11.

```
=======================================================
NetworkManager-openvpn-1.8.0
Overview of changes since NetworkManager-openvpn-1.2.10
=======================================================

This is a new stable release of NetworkManager-openvpn.  Notable changes include:

* Use gresources for ui files.
* Use NMACertChooser for PKCS#11 support.
* Support --ifconfig option not only for static key connections (bgo#774727).
* Fix import for key-direction to make it independent of the order (bgo#778154).
* Extend support for address family specifier for remote protocol (bgo#731620).
* Updated Brazilian Portuguese, Catalan, Czech, Hungarian, Indonesian, Italian,
  Lithuanian, Polish, Serbian, Spanish, Swedish translations.
```

I want to install my certificate in a Yubikey PIV slot and use a provider like opensc-pkcs11 to choose the certificate when connection to an OpenVPN connection.

However there are no GUI opens and I can't find any documentation supporting the statement in the change log.

Would someone be able to help guide me with this? I do know that it works using standard OpenVPN on Linux from the cli with both Yubikey and TPM with pkcs11 but I can't see a way to do it with NetworkManager.

Thank you in advance.

ref. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/NetworkManager-openvpn/-/blob/1.10.2/NEWS